# inheritance with diffrent constructors and obejct created in parent

Tags: php, oop, inheritance, extends, symfony5

- The `class A` has a constructor with some Interfaces.
- The `class A` has a `__construct` where a new object `$this->foo = new FooController();` will be spawned
- The `class B extends A` but has its own `__construct` with only one param. calling `parent::__construct()` with the same params of `A::__construct` does not work since this changes the `B::__construct`
- `class B` accesses `$this->foo` which was created in the constructor of `class A`

How create `$b = new B($some_variable='foo');` without reusing all constructor variables of `A::class` and have the `$b->foo` avaliable (which was created in `A::class` ?

Your hints are highly appreciated.

---

```php
class A extends AbstractController
{
    protected FooController $foo;
    protected EntityManagerInterface $manager;
    protected Security $security;
    protected RequestStack $requestStack; 

    public function __construct(EntityManagerInterface $manager, Security $security, RequestStack $requestStack)
    {
        $this->manager = $manager;
        $this->security = $security;
        $this->requestStack = $requestStack;

        $this->foo = new FooController();
    }
}

class B extends A
{
    public function __construct($some_variable)
    {
        parent::__construct()
        $this->foo = $some_variable;
    }
}
```

Comment: Why aren't you injecting `FooController` too?

Comment: @msg because the `FooController` is not an interface but an entity object.

`Cannot autowire service argument "$foo" of method "A::__construct()" references class "App\Entity\Foo" but no such service exists.`

Comment: You can then delegate the object creation to a Factory and inject that. Short story short, you obviously can't pull the variables out of thin air, so it's not possible without extending `A::__construct` signature.